# Apache spark Web UI on Amazon EMR not working

Tags: apache-spark, emr

We are using Spark on Amazon EMR 4.1. When accessing application master link on yarn resource manager we are seeing a blank page. Using Firefox debugging, we noticed that we got a HTTP 500 error. We have tried configuring proxy settings for AWS and also replacing the URL's internal hostname with external hostname/ip address but are still not able to access the web ui.

The same steps worked for us in the past on EMR 3.x version.

Comment: Does the url starts with ip or ec2?

Comment: Thanks for your response. The URL starts with ip-. I have also tried adding ip* regular expression in my proxy settings

Comment: I would say to start fresh, follow docs to setup a socks proxy with ssh tunneling, verify RM works then run sample MapReduce job (could just use s3-dist-cp).  See if it's AppMaster URL works. If so, then run one of the example Spark apps and try AppMaster URL again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems like your proxy, I had the same problem 
Add this sbt repository or maven, whatever you use

SBT

```
"org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy"
```

Maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

its working for me

Answer (score -1):

ip* is private ip address. You will not be able to access it directly. Either you need to use public ip which starts with ec2 or you need to use ssh tunneling via the server with public ip.

Are you using SSH tunneling?

When add new entry with any where, it is working for me with public ip. I am sure it will work with private ip as well

[image: as depicted]

Comment: We have tried with both the methods by replacing private IP with public IP and by using SSH tunneling but its not working with it.

Comment: Have you validated security group to see whether the port for resource manager is enabled?

Comment: Yes. Just ensured that its open for 20888 and we also have tried opening all TCP-everywhere too. Still not able to access